# Pandas for each primary key keep only the row having the max value into another column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I keep for each element in Customer_ID only the Col2_ID and Qta with the maximum value of the Qta column and discard all the rest?

I'm stuck here:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "Col2_ID"]).Qta.sum()

Customer_ID  Col2_ID       Qta
0           536544      600
            536546        1
            536550        1
            536553        3
            536555        1
                       ... 
18283       579673      134
            580872      142
18287       554065      488
            570715      990
            573167      108
```

After grouping I have for each customer multiple (Col2_ID, Qta), but for each Customer I only want the (Col2_ID, Qta) with maximum value.

For example instead of the output given by my program, the output I need would be

```
Customer_ID  Col2_ID       Qta
0           536544      600
                       ... 
18283       580872      142
18287       570715      990
```

I'm new to pandas and in the documentation I can't find what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain it with [**`df.max`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) which takes `level` as parameter. At *level 0* it takes max from every `Customer_ID`.

```
df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "Col2_ID"]).Qta.sum().max(level=0)
```

Here, you will index as `Customer_ID` only to get both `Customer_id` and `Col2_ID` as index try this.

```
out = df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "Col2_ID"]).Qta.sum().reset_index(level=1)
idx = out['Qta'].max(level=0).index
out.loc[idx].set_index('Col2_ID', append=True)
```

Now, here index of `out` is `MultiIndex` with `Customer_ID` and `Col2_ID`